# switch-case executing default case in cygwin(using notepad++)

Tags: bash, cygwin, switch-statement

```
while true ; do
  read -p "Proced with installation:(y/n) ?" ans
  case ans in 
    "y"|"y" )
       echo "y";  break ;;
    "n"|"N" )
       echo "n";   break ;;
    * )
       echo "invalid choice=$ans enter again : ";  
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the following line:

```
case ans in
```

You wanted to say:

```
case $ans in
```

Saying `case ans in` causes `bash` to choose the default case because you don't have any `case` named `ans`!

Moreover, you probably wanted to say:

```
"y"|"Y" )
```

instead of

```
"y"|"y" )
```

Comment: thanks devnull , it is working now